# How to modify deprecated imports for a reusable app?

Tags: python, django

My project depends on an OSS reusable app, and that app includes a Django import which is deprecated in Django 1.10:

`from django.db.models.sql.aggregates import Aggregate`

is changing to:

`from django.db.models.aggregates import Aggregate`

We get a warning on Django 1.9, which will become an error on Django 1.10. This is blocking our upgrade, and I want to contribute a fix to the app so we can upgrade.

One option would be to modify the requirements in setup.py so that Django 1.10 is required. But I'm sure my contribution would be rejected since it would break for everyone else.

To maintain backwards compatibility, I can do the import as a `try/except` but that feels hacky. It seems like I need to do some Django version checking in the imports.  Should I do a Django version check, which returns a string, convert that to a float, and do an `if version > x`? That feels hacky too.

What's the best practice on this? Examples?

Answer (score 1):

Django has a strict backwards compatibility policy. If it's raising a deprecation warning, then the new version *works already* in 1.9. You should just switch to it before you upgrade.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response Daniel. Our project is blocked from upgrading to Django 1.10 by one reusable app. I want to help fix this reusable app. The question is *how* should I fix it?

Comment: Well now it's me that doesn't understand. If you're making a change to that app, make it import from the right place, surely?

Comment: Right, but the question is, *how* to do that? Via try/except or checking the current version? I've had trouble Googling for examples.

Comment: The problem is that I want to do it without breaking backwards compatibility for that app.

Comment: The project owner has just stated that they are willing to break backwards compatibility, so it looks like I don't need to solve this after all, but am still curious how one would fix a shared app while maintaining backwards compatibility.